# Go graceful shutdown negative WaitGroup

Tags: go

I have tried to implement a graceful shutdown of the go server, as described in this blog post http://grisha.org/blog/2014/06/03/graceful-restart-in-golang/. The main bits are the following.

Custom listener:

```
var httpWg sync.WaitGroup  // initialised in the other part

type gracefulListener struct {
    net.Listener
    stop    chan error
    stopped bool
}

func newGracefulListener(l net.Listener) (gl *gracefulListener) {
    gl = &gracefulListener{Listener: l, stop: make(chan error)}
    go func() {
        _ = <-gl.stop
        gl.stopped = true
        gl.stop <- gl.Listener.Close()
    }()
    return
}

func (gl *gracefulListener) Accept() (c net.Conn, err error) {
    c, err = gl.Listener.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    c = gracefulConn{Conn: c}  // wrap using our custom connection

    httpWg.Add(1)  // increase the counter
    return
}

func (gl *gracefulListener) Close() error {
    if gl.stopped {
        return syscall.EINVAL
    }
    gl.stop <- nil
    return <-gl.stop
}

func (gl *gracefulListener) File() *os.File {
    tl := gl.Listener.(*net.TCPListener)
    fl, _ := tl.File()
    return fl
}
```

Custom Conn:

```
type gracefulConn struct {
    net.Conn
}

func (w gracefulConn) Close() error {
    httpWg.Done()  // <- panics sometimes
    return w.Conn.Close()
}
```

The idea is when the program receives SIGTERM, it stops serving new connections and just waits for the `httpWg.Wait()` for existing connections to finish.
This approach works locally, but when I deploy it, sometimes I receive a panic in the `gracefulConn.Close()` at `httpWg.Done()` line:

```
panic: sync: negative WaitGroup counter
```

The panic happens not when I stop the server but just during routine serving.
How is it possible, that there are more `Close()` calls then `Accept()` calls? Or am I missing something?

P.S. I have tried to add `stopped` property and a mutex to `gracefullConn`, so in `Close` it locks the mutex and checks `stopped` to ensure we stop it only once. However, I still received the same panic.

Comment: most likely `Close()` is called twice on the same gracefulConn instance. It is hard to tell how this happens without seeing the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Close()` can be called multiple times so you definitely need to check for that in `func (w gracefulConn) Close() error`.

> P.S. I have tried to add stopped property and a mutex to gracefullConn, so in Close it locks the mutex and checks stopped to ensure we stop it only once. However, I still received the same panic.

Keep in mind that `gracefulConn` if passed as a value not a reference so any mutexes/flags will not work as expected. So be sure to turn `c = gracefulConn{Conn: c}` into `c = &gracefulConn{Conn: c}`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the wrong approach.

You don't really care about whether the connection is open or not - what about persistent connections?

What you care about is whether you are actively using those connections.  You'd be better off putting your `WaitGroup` into a custom `ServeMux` into the `ServeHTTP` method I think. You can then have the `WaitGroup` around a function call.